# VML responsive background iamges

Tags: html-email, vml

How can i make background images in VML responsive?

To enable outlook compatibility i have added a VML background to my email. This is how it looks like

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:900px;height:600px">
          <v:fill type="tile" size="100%,100%" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/valiram.vmailbuilder.images/44/background.jpg" color="#333333" ></v:fill>
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
     <![endif]-->
[table content here]
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
               </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
```

v:rect is set to a fixed width. How can i make it responsive to the size of the screen. I have tried "100%" and "auto". Does'nt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been trying to fix this, no solution yet. Tried having media queries, no luck. It only works when i set the style attribute to a certain width. This is specific for older versions of outlook (2011)

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement but still not a full solution.  I offer it so that it might help others to come to a full solution (if it is even possible).

Although VML only works in Outlook, and thus you should be using media queries and fluid-hybrid to achieve a responsive background image in all other places, Outlook mobile is still a problem.

My first suggestion with your above code is that you have

```
<v:fill type="tile"
```

you could change it to

```
<v:fill type="frame"
```

This will stop it repeating.  Which can be a real issue.  If you want it to repeat then don't change that code.  But the image you have choosen looks to me like it is not meant to repeat.

I have managed to make it the right height, and cut off the right hand side, which for my image actually worked quite well.  But it is not responsive.  However, for your example it would cut off the V.  That may be acceptable, or you may be able to retake the shot with the V on the left hand side.  So this is not an ideal solution and I'll keep searching for one.

Here's how I achieve it:

```
<!-- Full width background image with content.  Image is full width but 200px high -->
<div mc:repeatable="options" mc:variant="Main Background Image with Text overlay">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;min-height:328px;height:328px;" background="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fa85a578f928f05fa5750d667/images/cc24d737-fea1-4a47-87fb-517f5fecb2f4.jpg">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 20px; font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect style="width:600px;height:328px;" strokecolor="none" stroke="false">
                    <v:fill type="frame" color="#303131" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fa85a578f928f05fa5750d667/images/cc24d737-fea1-4a47-87fb-517f5fecb2f4.jpg" /></v:fill>
                </v:rect>
                <v:shape id="bgImage" style="position:absolute;width:600px;height:328px;">
                <![endif]-->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 238px;">&nbsp;</td>
<!-- this is just a spacer to force the heading down -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="h1 bold white" mc:edit="background-image-h1">
                            My Heading Text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:shape>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- END Full width background image with content.  Image is full width but 200px high -->
```

I think you have used Stigs solution https://backgrounds.cm/ but I find the above a little easier to manage and found it on https://blog.edmdesigner.com/background-images-in-modern-html-emails/

I saved it as a Gist for easy finding later https://gist.github.com/uglyeoin/d8dde956e5a72558de07cf2a240a15c0

Feel free to commit to the gist if you find a better solution.  I'll do a write up and show my full workings at some point.  I hope this brings you at least another step forwards.

Comment: Here is the VML information but I don't think mobiles were about when it was written. https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858386

Comment: Also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/vml/msdn-online-vml-width-attribute which indicates we can use percentages, although it must be 1000 not 100 and auto but was updated very recently, although deprecated in 2011